# Functional Testing with django-haystack and Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using `django-haystack` to implement search functionality in a Django app with Elasticsearch. How can I run functional tests of my app's search functionality with selenium, given that the model instances that are added in the tests aren't indexed? Is there some way to mock an Elasticsearch index, or another accepted way of artificially creating indexed results?

Comment: could you share how should your test look? about mocking you can always mock an entire service (I assume you return elacticsearch results through them).